# How to prevent hudson from sending multiple emails for cron job failures

Tags: email, cron, hudson, jobs

I have a job in Hudson which monitors the environment.
The requirement is the job should get built periodically and send a mail when the env is down.
But it should stop sending mails if the status of the job in last run is fail and an email has already been sent. How to setup this trigger in Hudson?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you aren't already doing so, you should be using **[email-ext](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin)** plugin for sending emails.

Once that is installed, in your post-build actions, use `"Editable Email Notification"`.

In there, click `"Advanced..."` button to setup triggers that control when (and to whom) and email is sent.

You need at least 2 triggers: `Failure` and `Still Failing`.
"Failure" will be triggered when the job fails for the first time. Send the email to everyone whom you want to include.
"Still Failing" will be triggered if there are subsequent failures. In this case, leave the recipient list unchecked (or send only to admin).

You can also use the `Fixed` trigger. This will send the email after the build recovers from failure (but not on subsequent successes)